# how to get piecharts for windows phone 7 without using third party tools

Tags: windows-phone-7, charts

Iam using windows phone 7.1. I need to draw a pie chart in windows phone. I googled, i could find only third party tools available. I am in situation that i could not use third party tools.I tried with System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.dll, but my app gets crashed 
when iam using this dll and it is saying "unsafe" while adding to reference also.Can anybody provide me any code for pie chart by using other drawing controls available in WP7 such as eclipse or arc?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you use a 3rd party library? some are open source, so you have access to their source code.

Comment: i used some of the open source.They have suggested the libraries will run on both sliverlight and windows phone 7, but when i attach the library to my wP7 references it says that library is not built on windows phone runtime so it cannot be attached to the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the svg tag inside a WebBrowser control.
http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_svg.asp

Answer (score 0):

I haven't stumbled upon an in built feature that can be used to build pie charts and if you look at Microsoft's official Dev Center app, you'll see that even they use third party tools for their charts (I believe they use Telerik). If you absolutely can't try third party libraries then try what Diomedes Dominguez suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could be useful for you!
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/wp7/article.php/c20199/How-to-Create-Charts--Graphs-in-Your-Windows-Phone-Application.htm